# Next Js: my project is not rendering the sass files on Static HTML

Tags: css, sass, next.js, build, static-html

I have a problem: I have a Next Js project that I need to upload as a static HTML page, but I'm facing an issue while exporting / building the files.

Here are the some notes regarding what I'm doing:

- I've used both `next build && next export` commands to build a Static HTML
- I'm using SASS to stylize my page
- The SASS files are being used as a module

But, every time I try to build the page, the styling files are not rendering and this is not happening on my local environment.

My `next.config.mjs` file is looking like this:

```
import path from "path"

function defineNextConfig(config) {
  return config;
}

export default defineNextConfig({
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join('/', 'pages')],
  },
});
```

Could it be an issue with the next commands? I'm not sure.

I appreciate the help! :D